# What is the link of the origin of a polyhedral fan?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, tropical-geometry

I am trying to understand the article
http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3651
by David Helm and Eric Katz. There the link of the origin of a polyhedral fan is mentioned. I googled and only found definitions that seemed to suggest that the link of a polyhedral fan at the origin is the fan itself. This doesn't seem right, why bother to call it the link of the origin if it were the same as the original fan. Please, does anyone know the correct definition?

Thank you,
Lars